# Placing UI AS3 on ZBar Camera (ANE)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flashdevelop, zbar

i'm trying to place some UI that i made with `as3` (on flash) on top off camera that called from `ZBar ANE` to read `QR Code`.

Can someone tell me how to do that?

I tried to place add after and before called the scanner, but not show. i think because the camera called from the activity of android, not in `AIR`.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely this will be impossible. The native components in use by the ZBar ANE will display outside (and above) the AIR display list and so you won't be able to place AIR display objects above them.

You'll have to either create native UI components in the extension or find another way to display the ZBar interface.

Comment: This is absolutely correct. It is impossible without modifying the ANE to add native GUI components.